# One to many database to json

Tags: c#, json, sql-server-2017

I got stuck when I retrieve data from database that is one to many relationship and I get two rows like this

```
ID   NAME   CHOICE_ID CHOICE_NAME CHOICE_VALUE
1     1         1          1          true
1     1         1          2          false
```

How can I make a json like this?

```
[{
    id:1
    name:1
    choice:[
          {
           choiceId:1
           choiceName:1
           choice_value:true
          },
          {
           choiceId:1
           choiceName:2
           choiceValue:false
           }
      ]
]}
```

My code is like :

```
 var tbl = from a in db.users
           join b in db.choice
           on a.choice_id = b.choice_id

           select new {
             a.id
             a.name
             a.choice_id
             b.choice_name
             b.choice_value
           }

        table.Select(p => new User()
        {
           id = p.id
           name = p.name
           choice = new List<Choice>()
           {
             new Choice()
             {
               choiceId = p.choiceId
               choiceName = p.choiceName
               choiceValue = p.choiceValue
             }
           }
        }).toList();
```

It's will get two with the same id and name I want to get one that contain all choice.

Comment: Some databases can return the json structure themselves. What rdbms are you working with? [edit] your question to include the product and specific version tags.

Comment: What's the relationship about `c# `and `api`?

Comment: You can convert your query result list to `json`.

Comment: yes but how to fix structure?

Comment: I can give you a pure t-sql solution using FOR JSON that will return the json structure directly from SQL Server. Would you like that?

Comment: sure, can u give me that.

Answer (score 3):

So a pure T-SQL Solution would be something like this:

```
SELECT Id, 
       Name,
       (
           SELECT choice_id, choice_Name, choice_Value
           FROM choice c
           WHERE c.choice_id = u.choice_id
           FOR JSON AUTO
        ) As choice
FROM users u
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: my problem is it return multiple columns in sub query then it's error

Comment: You are not returning multiple columns in the subquery, you are returning a single value containing json - have you missed the `FOR JSON AUTO` in the subquery?

Comment: Why i can't use  FOR JSON AUTO in my sql server?

Comment: Do you get an error message? Json support was added in 2016 version, so unless your [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) is set lower than 130, it should be supported out of the box.

Comment: Oh i use old laptop it run on window 7 and using Sql server 2012. thank you for answer the question i will try with another computer.

Comment: @ZoharPeled how can I get only the users where amount of choices is at least one? In my case I don't want users without choices in my result. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob-JanMosselman If you have a question please post one with all the relevant details, so that people can actually answer it.

Answer (score 1):

First is the query. You'll need to work in a "Group By" that groups the entities on the `id` and `name` and have the child entities underneath it.

```
    var result = tbl
        .GroupBy(p => new { p.id, p.name })
        .Select(g => new
        {
           id = g.Key.id,
           name = g.Key.name,
           choice = g.Select(p => 
             new Choice()
             {
               choiceId = p.choiceId
               choiceName = p.choiceName
               choiceValue = p.choiceValue
             })
        }).toList();
```

Second, to get it in JSON depends on the libraries you're using. With C# it's likely the .Net Web API or MVC. Either way you can wire it to serialize its responses to JSON which is an entirely different question. If you want to serialize it to a variable directly I'd recommend the `Newtonsoft.Json` which would be a pretty simple call at this point:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```